# What's the term in java when you call a method from one class to another

Tags: java, oop

I'm sorry if I'm not clear enough but for instance, I'm just a beginner so please go easy on me. Ok let's say we have two classes in separate files

```
    public class testA{

    private ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(); // This list will be called from testB class

    public testA(){

    }


    }

    // End of class testA. Let's assume they are on 2 separate files

    public class testB{

    private testA tA;

    public testB(testA tA){ // class testA passed in the contructor of this class
    this.tA = tA        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(tA.myList); // calling the list from class testA           
    }
```

Comment: Just inheritance

Comment: You're not calling anything, since you can only "call" a method. You're "using" / "accessing" the instance field directly. Or rather, you're trying, because it'll fail compilation, given that field is declared `private`.

Comment: In the `main` method… where is `tA` instantiated?  I am confident you will get a compile time error on the line: `System.out.print(tA.myList);` because `tA` does not exist. In other words where is `tA = new testA()` or `tA = new testB(someothertestA)`? Even if `tA` is created, as Andreas points out… the list `myList`is private.

Comment: @JohnG  `tA` in `testB` is initiated by the constructor.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I would call it: trying to (incorrectly) access `testA` class variable. Incorrectly because as @Andreas pointed out  you can't accesses `myList` from another class because it is declared private.  Also, to use `tA` in a static context (`System.out.print(tA.myList);`  from `main`)  you'll have to declare `tA` in `testB` as static : `private static testA tA;`

Comment: p.s try to avoid posting code which does not compile, and use Java naming convention (`TestA` , `TestB`)

Comment: @C0der then where is `testB` instantiated? Its not! Even if the code was correct... `tA` DNE in the current context because it is never created..

Comment: `testB` initiation is indeed missing from `main` : `new testB(new testA());`

Comment: a setter function?

Answer (score 0):

`Inheritance` can be a term that you are reffering to.., when you do `Inheritance`

you extends the child class with the parent class with it you can use the method of your parent class and data fields of your parent class

example: let us change your class name to follow 
naming convention

`public class TestB extends TestA` <--- meaning `TestB` can use all of the data fields and methods of `TestA`

`TestA` is the parent class `TestB` is the child class to use inheritance you use the keyword `extends` at the class header

then at your main method

```
`TestB lettterB= new TestB();`
`letterB.methodOfTestA();`
```

note that only public data fields can be access by `TestB` class directly or you can setup a setter and getter method then you can also set the datafields of `TestA` to become `protected` meaning the parent and the child class is the only class who can access it

Comment: I don't see inheritance. I see trying to (incorrectly) accessing testA class variable.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the second sentence in your question…

> *”Ok let's say we have two classes in separate files”*

What is your question? Yes, you have two classes that are in separate files; however, in their current posted form neither class is going to be very helpful.

I am clueless where “Inheritance” came into this picture. Neither class demonstrates an “Inheritance” of one class based upon another class. I am unaware of any formal terminology that describes one class using another class. I am guessing it is called “using one class in another class”.

To help I will try to describe WHY the current code will not work, and a possible solution so that it will work.

Let us start with the posted class `testA` below:

```
public class testA{
  private ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
  public testA(){
  }
}
```

The above class will compile, however the compiler/IDE (I am using Eclipse Neon3) SHOULD be flagging the `myList` variable as a variable that is “never used”, and this would certainly be true since the class gives no way for this variable to be accessed. Example if the two lines below are executed in the main method…

```
testA tA = new testA();
System.out.print(tA.myList);
```

This will cause a compile time error stating that `myList` is not visible. This error is correct because `myList` is declared as `private` in the class. Therefore, there is no way to access the variable `myList`. In the code you posted it appears you DO want to access this ‘myList’ variable. In order to have access to this variable you either have to make `myList` public OR create a “getter” in the class to access `myList`.

You may want to look up how “getters and setters” are used, as they are the technique that most classes use to access the variables in the class. In other words… without a getter or setter for a private variable, then ONLY the internal class itself can access this variable.

To keep the variable private, a getter would look similar to the code below which you would add to the `testA` class to allow `testA` objects to access the `myList` variable:

```
public ArrayList<String> GetMyList() {
  return myList;
}
```

After you add this method to the `testA` class then the little squiggly line under `myList` indicating the variable is never used will go away because NOW it IS being used. This is how you would GET the `myList` variable. Now you have access to `myList` and can add/delete strings to `myList`. If you make the variable `myList` public, then you will not have to create the “GetMyList()” method. Normal convention suggest that all class variables be private and have getters and setters.

Below is the code that corrects these `testA` class deficiencies using a getter.

```
public class TestA {

  private ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
  // blank constructor
  public TestA(){
  }
  // getter method to give access to myList
  public ArrayList<String> GetMyList() {
    return myList;
  }
}
```

Now to class `testB` shown below

```
public class testB{
  private testA tA;
  public testB(testA tA){ 
     this.tA = tA        
  }
}
```

The class `testB` above creates a private `testA` variable called `tA`. Again since the variable `tA` is private, there is no way to access this variable and the compiler should complain about an unused variable. This is the same problem just described above. You either need to make `tA` public or create a getter method for it. A single constructor for `testB` takes a `testA` object called `tA` and assigns this variable to the `testB` variable `this.tA`. This works as expected, but again there will be no way to access this variable `this.tA` without `tA` being declared public or a getter is created for it. If we create a getter for `tA` then we will have access to it. Below is the added getter for the variable `tA` in the class `testB`. This will return a `testA` object from a `testB` object.

```
public testA Get_tA() {
  return tA;
}
```

Now the variables in the classes are at least accessible.

Finally, moving on to the main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print(tA.myList);            
}
```

The code above has one huge problem… Where is `tA` created? In its present form the compiler should be complaining about an undefined variable `tA` that cannot be resolved. This is true because `tA` is never created using class `testA` OR class `testB`. To fix this you need to create `tA`. Since class `testB` does not have a blank constructor, the only class we can use is class `testA`. The code below creates a NEW `testA` object…

```
testA tA = new TestA();
```

NOW `tA` exist and it has an empty list. Now the compiler will not complain about the undefined variable `tA` at the line `System.out.print(tA.myList);`. Unfortunately, the compiler will quit complaining about the undefined variable `tA` and start complaining about `myList`. Since the variable `myList` is private, you will not be able to access `myList` this way (`tA.myList`). Fortunately the added getter method CAN access `myList`. Therefore, we simply need to change the line to look like:

```
System.out.print(tA.GetMyList());
```

This final change should now make the compiler happy and it should run properly. Unfortunately, the line printed out will be empty because there are no items in the list. To make sure this works… lets add some items to the list like below.

```
ArrayList<String> classAList = tA.GetMyList(); 
classAList.add("AddedString1");
classAList.add("AddedString2");
```

Now that some strings have been added to the list, they should print out properly with the line:

```
System.out.print(tA.GetMyList());
```

Normal naming conventions always start class names with an uppercase character. This class will still work with a lowercase starting character; however, it causes confusion later in your code because most “variables” start with lower case letters. Therefore, when someone else reads your code, they will have to adjust to a code that does not conform to normal coding conventions. The changes below try to follow normal naming conventions.

The code below uses both classes to demonstrate how you would use them.

TestA Class

```
public class TestA {
  private ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
  // blank constructor
  public TestA(){
  }
  // getter method to give access to myList
  public ArrayList<String> GetMyList() {
    return myList;
  }
}
```

TestB Class

```
public class TestB {
  private TestA tA;

  public TestB(TestA tA){ 
    this.tA = tA;      
  }

  public TestA Get_tA() {
    return tA;
  }
}
```

Main method to test both classes

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  // test for TestA class
  TestA tA = new TestA();
  ArrayList<String> classAList = tA.GetMyList(); 
  classAList.add("AddedString From class TestA 1");
  classAList.add("AddedString From class TestA 2");
  System.out.println(tA.GetMyList());

  // test for class TestB using the TestA class from above
  TestB tB = new TestB(tA);
  ArrayList<String> testAList = tB.Get_tA().GetMyList();
  testAList.add("AddedString From Class TestB 1");
  testAList.add("AddedString From Class TestB 2");
  System.out.println(tB.Get_tA().GetMyList());

}
```

Hope this helps.